# My modifying only works on the referenced index. How do I get it to work on any index chosen?

Tags: python

I want the user to choose the index. Not just to assign one in the code.

```
 def pending():
        if selection == 'P':
            (int(raw_input('Choose an item to mark pending and hit enter. ')))
            mylist.append(mylist[0] + '-' + "pending")
            del mylist[0]
            print mylist
            print ("\n")
            print 'What would you like to do next?'
            i = 0
            for list in mylist:
                print (i, list)
                i = i + 1
```

Comment: Save `(int(raw_input('Choose an item to mark pending and hit enter. ')))` by making it something like `my_index = (int(raw_input('Choose an item to mark pending and hit enter. ')))` then instead of `mylist[0]` use `mylist[my_index]`

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly now! Thank you for the my_index, that really helps to read and understand it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = (int(raw_input('Choose an item to mark pending and hit enter. ')))
mylist.append(mylist[x] + '-' + "pending")
```

I think this is what you need.If no, please add more explanation to the question.